# What is the data type of 0XB when it was assign to variable like this $a = 0XB

Tags: php

As I mentioned earlier, in the script below, I don't know what is the data type of "0XB"?

```
$a = 0XB;
$b= 1;
$c= $a + $b;
var_dump($c);
```

The result is 12, which means 0XB is 11, I am not sure how PHP interpreter 0XB is equal to 11.

Can someone give me an explanation regarding this one and the use cases of this data type?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Read about the [integer type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) in the PHP documentation.

Comment: You can get a direct answer from PHP by using [gettype()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettype), see: https://3v4l.org/tHZIe It's an integer and `B` is [hexadecimal](http://ctp.mkprog.com/en/php/hexadecimal_literals/) for `11`.